# @ngrx/data - how can I extend a collection reducer / replace handling of the results of a data service call?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

Using **@ngrx/data** I want to handle the result of the `getWithQuery` API call differently than the default.

Currently **if** this returns an array of entities, this gets loaded in the `entityCache` directly.

So far I've used the standard pattern shown in the [overview](https://ngrx.io/guide/data#creating-entity-data-services):

```
export const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  PurchaseOrder: {}
};
```

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class PurchaseOrderService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<
  PurchaseOrder
> {
  constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory) {
    super("PurchaseOrder", serviceElementsFactory);
  }
}
```

---

**Instead** I want to handle the following API response and load the `entities` in the entityCache as the normal `getWithQuery` would but also stick the `total` elsewhere in my store.

```
{
    "entities": [{...}, {...}, ..., {...}],    // list of entities
    "total": 100
}
```

Naturally I get the following error if this API response is returned:

### [image]

My understanding is that a default reducer gets created and registered for each entity providing the [EntityCollectionDataService](https://ngrx.io/api/data/EntityCollectionDataService) interface with the `add / delete / getAll / getById / getWithQuery / update` methods.

**I want to keep these methods but override the `getWithQuery` reducer to achieve my aim.**

This is mentioned in [Customizing Entity Reducer Behavior](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-reducer#customizing-entity-reducer-behavior)

> But quite often you'd like to extend a collection reducer with some additional reducer logic that runs before or after.

**How can this be actually done?**

I still get the above error if I try to override `getWithQuery` inside my `PurchaseOrderService`

```
  getWithQuery(params) {
    return super.getWithQuery(params).pipe(tap(result => console.log(result)));
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to get this working using a custom [EntityDataService](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice#custom-entitydataservice)

```
@Injectable()
export class PurchaseOrderDataService extends DefaultDataService<
  PurchaseOrder
> {
  constructor(
    http: HttpClient,
    httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator,
    logger: Logger,
    config: DefaultDataServiceConfig
  ) {
    super("PurchaseOrder", http, httpUrlGenerator, config);
  }

  getWithQuery(params: string | QueryParams): Observable<PurchaseOrder[]> {
    return super.getWithQuery(params).pipe(
      tap(res => console.log(res)),
      map((res: any) => res.entities)
    );
  }
}
```

Then this needs to be registered:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [PurchaseOrderDataService] // <-- provide the data service
})
export class EntityStoreModule {
  constructor(
    entityDataService: EntityDataService,
    purchaseOrderDataService: PurchaseOrderDataService
  ) {
    entityDataService.registerService(
      "PurchaseOrder",
      purchaseOrderDataService
    ); // <-- register it
  }
}
```

And import this alongside `EntityDataModule.forRoot({ entityMetadata }),`

Comment: Hello, but where are you passing the custom structure '{entities": [{...}, {...}, ..., {...}], "total":100}' to the state? Getting the same doubt, since I need to add more properties to the state, pagination in this case. Tks.

Comment: The documentation doesn't have a good code example https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-reducer#collection-reducer-factory

Comment: @FaustoBraz I'd actually use a slightly different method now [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553070/4711754) but I'll explain above - doing `map((res: any) => res.entities)` means the default reducer kicks in and adds the entities to the state. In the above example total is not saved. My link gives a way of saving additional properties to a collection. I believe Pagination to be dependent on actual details - can you either ask a new question or in the [ngrx gitter channel](https://gitter.im/ngrx/platform). Keep an eye on the issues on ngrx platform github eg. #2434

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, this won't actually add the total to your store. To do that, follow the tutorial here: https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-metadata#additionalcollectionstate